# Dynamically-generated table keeps multiplying even though it's being cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variety of fields I'm appending to a table (#dvdCollectionBody) in my function loadDvdCollectionView().

The problem: if I click the  tag that calls my displayDvd() function, then hit the 'Back' button, everything works as it should. If I click the  tag, calling displayDvd() a second time, then click the 'Back' button again, the table will be duplicated, indicating that rows are being appended that aren't getting cleared.

I cannot for the life of me understand why the table keeps appending itself, but only after repeating the process of clicking a 'td' tag more than once.

```html
$(document).ready(function () {

    loadDvdCollectionView();

    // create on a click
    createDvd();

});
```

```html
function loadDvdCollectionView(){
  // hide errors
  $('#errorDiv').hide(); 

  // show this view 
  $('#viewingTable').show(); 

  // empty table body of any preexisting data
  $('#dvdCollectionBody').empty();

  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/dvds",

  success:
  function (data, status) { $.each(data, function (index, dvd) { 
  
  // append DVD collection to table rows in #dvdCollectionBody 
  var dvdRow = '<tr><td onclick="displayDvd(' + dvd.dvdId + ')">' + .......

$('#dvdCollectionBody').append(dvdRow);
  });
}
```

```html
// called when <td> tag is clicked

function displayDvd(dvdId){

    //hide viewingTable 
    $('#viewingTable').hide();

    // empty preexisting data 
    $('#releaseYearDisplay, #directorDisplay, #ratingDisplay, #notesDisplay, #dvdTitleHeader').empty(); 

    // show table 
    $('#dvdDetailsDisplay, #dvdTitleHeader').show();

    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: "http://localhost:8080/dvd/" + dvdId, 
    success: function (data) { 
    $('#dvdTitleHeader').append('
    <h3>' + data.title + '</h3>'); $('#releaseYearDisplay').append('
    <h3>' + data.releaseYear + '</h3>'); $('#directorDisplay').append('
    <h3>' + data.director + '</h3>'); $('#ratingDisplay').append('
    <h3>' + data.rating + '</h3>'); $('#notesDisplay').append('
    <h3>' + data.notes + '</h3>'); }
    } 
    });
  
  
  $('#backButton').click(function(){
  
      // hide current display and header 
      $('#dvdDetailsDisplay, #dvdTitleHeader').hide();

      // load main view again 
      loadDvdCollectionView(); 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, this piece of code:

```
$('#backButton').click(function(){
  // hide current display and header 
  $('#dvdDetailsDisplay, #dvdTitleHeader').hide();

  // load main view again 
  loadDvdCollectionView(); 
});
```

is placed inside your `displayDvd()` function.

So when the first time your `<td>` is clicked, the `displayDvd()` is called and your `#backButton` callback is added.
Then you hit the `#backButton`, the callback function is called, everything should work fine here.
However, when you hit the `<td>` 2nd time, `displayDvd()` is called again and **another click callback is added to `#backButton` again, also.**
This is where the bug occurred. Now your `#backButton` have 2 same click callback functions attached. So when you click on it, 2 `loadDvdCollectionView()` are called simultaneously.

Simply move the piece of code into `$(document).ready()` callback should fix the problem.

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot for helping me understand that!

Comment: @porter3 you're welcome, would be good if you could set me as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're hiding the DOM elements, but you're not removing them from the DOM. Try the following to remove the content from `dvdDetailsDisplay` and `dvdTitleHeader`:

```
$('#backButton').click(function(){
    // hide current display and header 
    $('#dvdDetailsDisplay, #dvdTitleHeader').empty();

    // load main view again 
    loadDvdCollectionView(); 
});
```